# Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity. .NETFramework Facades

Tags: c#, .net

On the same code branch we are successfully building on one machine, but on another we get this:

> Error     Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: '...\src\packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

How can we resolve?

Comment: All nuget packages? No, I haven't. I was hoping for a faster solution. I have a several projects with this issue.

Comment: I am able to get the solution to build by deleting references to the above package as well as System.Runtime and System.Runtime.InteropServices that were generating the same error.

Comment: I can get it to run by removing the dependent assemblies from the config files.
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by updating Visual Studio to the latest

Answer (score 5):

Using MSBuild 15 solves the problem.
MSBuild 15 is part of the [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) or can be downloaded using the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have both a directly referenced (via the GAC or file system via Browse...) dll and a Nuget package in your project.

Best to try uninstalling the Nuget package, and then check your references and uncheck any remaining references to `System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll`, and then install your Nuget reference again.

**UPDATE**

For reference, [a similar error was encountered with `System.Threading` when an EntityFramework package was renamed](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3407). Perhaps one of your packages has a newer version or has a renamed namespace? Or maybe you have incompatible versions of .NET Standard?

Comment: I get this error when uninstalling
Unable to uninstall 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.0' because 'NETStandard.Library.1.6.1' depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the "Error Multiple assemblies" problem by uninstalling Xamarin from computer and Visual Studio 15.

Followed this instruction: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/troubleshooting/uninstall-xamarinvs/

My problem occured when updating asp.net nuget packages from version 1.0.0 to 1.1.0.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any Xamarin installed.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14050

This explains that in v4.3.0 of the nuget package it requires using VS 2015 Build tools Update 3 or later.

If you can't upgrade, downgrade the package to v4.0.11.

Comment: Teamcity was breaking on 1 build. This was it.

Answer (score 1):

Made the following change to .csproj, which did the trick:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit">
   <Version>4.3.0</Version>
   <ExcludeAssets>All</ExcludeAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes looking for another answer. Can happen (6/6/2018) due to a package reinstall ambiguity between matching namespaces of NetStandard and .NET Framework.

Issue took root updating a NetStandard 3rd party package and it required/installed a dependency of `System.Net.NetworkInformation` (v4.3.0 I believe.) Honestly worked fine before that package so I manually removed the dependency from CSPROJ and package.config that main solution added.

It's not clean but demonstrates a NuGet or MSBuild issue not recognizing they are in fact different assemblies and thus count as a duplicate reference.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the dll in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. 
and build your code.

Add it back after build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the NuGet package **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** to a newer version. It had been at 1.0.0, which I believe wasn't using the newer version of MSBuild (as pointed out in some of the other answers).